# Angular: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm following this online tutorial. When I trie to add some styling to the form I keep getting this error. Do any of you have a solution?

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegisterComponent.html:14)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13844)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

This is my RegisterComponent.html

```
<h1 class="page-header">Registreer</h1>

<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Username" formControlName="username"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div [ngClass]="{'has-error': (form.controls.email.errors && forms.controls.email.dirty), 'has-succes': !form.controls.email.errors}">
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Email" formControlName="email"/>
      <ul class="help-block">
          <li>Je moet een email invullen</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
    <div>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Wachtwoord" formControlName="password"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirm">Bevestig wachtwoord</label>
    <div>
      <input type="password" name="confirm" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Bevestig wachtwoord" formControlName="confirm"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registreer" />

</form>
```

This is my RegisterComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      username: '',
      password: '',
      confirm: ''
    });
  }

  onRegisterSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I'm just following along the tutorial, so my component is not finished yet. But at this stage it should work for email according to the guy.

Comment: **forms** in `forms.controls.email.dirty` should be **form**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-error': (form.controls.email.errors && forms.controls.email.dirty), 'has-succes': !form.controls.email.errors}">
```

Basically the object `forms` is undefined.

Comment: @yurzui: yes, that is the issue. It is not defined in the Component ts file.

Comment: @Ian Martens You defined `form` not `forms`

Comment: I found it. It was a typo, it had to be form.controls.email.dirty instead of forms.controls.email.dirty

Comment: @IanMartens Consider marking this answer as solution if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `ngClass` to style the form based on the form validity. Angular adds some very useful classes you you.

[image]

Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel).

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with your and checked that you had a small thing to fix:

1. Typo in your template - "form" instead of "forms"

Check the solution below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctqzxq